# Как сделать подстановку случайного заданного значения "от - до" в ссылку, которая находится в коде?

Tags: javascript, html, алгоритм, кодировка, случайные-числа

У меня есть:

```
<A href="ссылка1/что/нибудь/значение11111"
    src="ссылка2/что/нибудь/значение22222" </A>
```

Нужно что бы в "значение11111" заменялось 11111 случайным заданным числом "от - до"
А в "значение22222" заменялось 22222 другим заданным числом "от - до"

Answer (score 0):

```js
function rand(max, min = 0) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

// находим нужную ссылку
const link = document.querySelector('a');

// выбираем значение ссылки
const href = link.href;
// или можно так
//const href = link.getAttribute('href');

// декодируем кириллические символы
const decodedHref = decodeURIComponent(link.href);

// заменяем последние цифры в строке
const replacedHref = decodedHref.replace(/\d+$/, rand(999999));

link.href = replacedHref;
// можно так
//link.setAttribute('href', replacedHref);
```

```html
<A href="ссылка1/что/нибудь/значение11111"
    src="ссылка2/что/нибудь/значение22222">AAA </A>
```

Comment: Я дико извиняюсь, а что за атрибут `src` в теге `A`?

Comment: Он картинку отображает по ссылке и там <IMG перед ним, стел случайно с:

Comment: Ну исправь...  Нажми кнопку `править` по вопросом...

Comment: @vihtor можешь подсказать куда именно вставить код и как, что бы это работало, я в этом вообще 0...

Comment: этот код нужно вставить в html-файл, в котором содержится сама ссылка. Ниже данной ссылки нужно добавить теги `<script></script>`, а между них вставить приведённый код. Но данный код будет работать только для одной, первой найденной, ссылки